# Shopping Cart Price Rule not applied when using "Subtotal greater than xxx"

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I set currency `IDR (Rupiah)` and i want to use shopping cart price rule on my store,

But This Rule not applied when i'm using Subtotal greater than **200000** (price example).

How to resolve this issue?

Please help me...

Comment: Did you check the price rule conditions?

Comment: yes, the price rule was correct, because in dollar currency this rule can be applied